# With maven-bundle-plugin how to put all bnd warnings in one file?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

When using Apache Maven with `maven-bundle-plugin`, how to put all `bnd` warnings in one file, disable console output?

For a big project the number of OSGi-related warnings is big, but they should be analyzed for set of bundles, not one. Putting them together in verbose maven output makes a mess.

UPDATE. Usage example

ALl `bnd/manifest` related stuff in `bnd.bnd` file,
not inside deep `pom.xml` structure

```
  <plugin>    <!-- (2) START -->
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <include>bnd.bnd</include>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>    <!-- (2) END -->
```

Comment: Could you post your current configuration of the plugin?

Comment: <include>bnd.bnd</include>